# Mouse and Keyboard events getting with Python in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, python-2.6, xlib

[Here it's a decision how to get queue of mouse events.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585647/how-can-i-monitor-mouse-events-with-python-xlib-instead-of-capture-them)
But it's locking the program window if I run the program in console and until I close the program I can do something just with this window. 
**How to** make it's non-blocking?
And the same trouble if I use *grab_keyboard()* method [from here](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_21.html#SEC20) - it's document with description of all methods.
**How to** create the same thing to keyboard grabbing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `Display.AllowEvents(Display, SyncKeyboard, CurrentTime)` upon receiving a keypress? Or if you don't want to grab any of them, `RECORD` would probably be the way to go.

Comment: No. Just first of all - start the script in shell console. And for the first case it's working(for mouse actions grabbing), but unfortunately for keyboard it's suxx.